# How to get privateKey from Metamask by code?

Tags: web3js, metamask, javascript

Try to create ether wallet by privateKey from Metamask account

Answer (score 4):

MetaMask does not provide a way to get the private key through code by design. Any interaction with accounts in MetaMask has to be done through the Web3 API, to prevent a (malicious) website from stealing a user's private keys.